# Have the CaseOwner Follow the Newly created Case

Tags: trigger, salesforce1-app, case, follow

I have a Trigger that creates a new case. I need to add code to the trigger that automatically has the case owner following the case so that they get a notification is salesforce1.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to insert an [`EntitySubscription` record](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm).